# Virtual mail domain which does not appear connected to canonical domain

Tags: email, hosting, postfix

Is it possible to host multiple mail domains on one physical (Postfix) server so that they appear totally separate?

In a normal virtual hosting setup, the mail server will still identify itself by its canonical  name and the "Received" headers will refer to that as well. However, I need to set up a virtual domain that does not appear connected to the canonical domain in any way.

I was thinking of the following:

- multiple IP addresses on the server
- MX records pointing to these different addresses (+ correct reverse records)
- multiple instances of Postfix running, one for each domain and bound to the respective IP

Does this sound reasonable, or is there a better solution?

If my description is not clear, please tell me so and I will try to explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, running separate IP addresses and copies of smtpd is the way to go.  You can still run one instance overall, you just need to setup extra smtpd processes in `master.cf` and give them separate myhostname values, which I'm pretty sure is the option that sets the banner address.

The only problem with this way of doing things is that all of the instances will accept mail for all of the virtual domains configured on the server, but I can't imagine this is a practical problem.